# Is the crankcase gasket really necessary

Tags: scooter, gasket, crankcase

I opened the crankcase of my scooter (PGO PMX Naked) to have a look at the clutch, and there was a gasket between case and cover. It looks like some type of cardboard material, extremely thin. Since the crank case houses dry parts, and has an air intake, I can't think of a reason why it would need to be sealed with a gasket. It is really hard to find PGO parts, specially where I live, but I am a bit afraid of putting it back together without knowing the implications. What is the risk of not sealing the crank case properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider making a gasket, either use the old one as a pattern or use the cover itself.

The gasket is used to absorb any imperfections between the surfaces so they do not "chatter" ie rub on each other and wear away.

Comment: In this case, even using Permatex RTV or what have you would most likely work without issue. As you said, you're just trying to keep the two surfaces so they aren't touching (or rather rubbing/rattling together).

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 but the skill to make a new paper gasket... :) had to make a few in the past - good skill to have.